# VBA copy and paste data

Tags: excel

I am new to VBA and am trying to create a VBA function for the following 
example:

In the input table, first I would like to copy and paste values in column B and C for group 1 into the tool tab,then I would like to grab the value of cell E2 from tool tab and paste it into cell B2 in the output tab, and then the same steps will be repeated for group 2,3,4... until empty row.

[image: screenshot]

Could someone help me? Thanks so much!

```
Sub test()
   Dim i As Integer
   Dim j As Integer
   lr = Worksheets("input").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   lrj = Worksheets("output").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
   For j = 2 To lrj
      Sheets("input").Select
      For i = 1 To lr
         If Sheets("input").Cells(i, 1) = Sheets("output").Range("A2").Offset(j - 2, 0) Then
            Range(Cells(i, 2), Cells(i, 3)).Select
            Selection.Copy
            Sheets("tool").Select
            Range("A2").Offset(i - 2, 0).Select
            ActiveSheet.Paste
            Sheets("input").Select
         End If
      Next i
      Sheets("tool").Select
      Range("E2").Select
      Selection.Copy
      Sheets("output").Select
      Range("B2").Select
      Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:=False, Transpose:=False
   Next j
End Sub
```

Comment: Your code keeps giving me an error massage and am not sure what's wrong with it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You dont need tp pass through the intermediate `tool` tab. You can write this formula in `B2` of the `output` tab then copy/paste it along column B:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((input!$B:$B+input!$C:$C)*(input!$A:$A=A2))
```

EDIT

If you insist to use the `tool` sheet, try this, supposing you have a valid formula in `tool!E2`:

```
Sub useTheToolSheet()
  Dim grp As Range, src As Range
  Set grp = Worksheets("input").Range("A2")
  Do While IsNumeric(grp.Value2)
  Set src = grp.Offset(, 1).Resize(, 2)
    Do While grp.Value2 = grp.Offset(1).Value2
       Set grp = grp.Offset(1)
       Set src = src.Resize(src.Rows.Count + 1)
    Loop
    Worksheets("tool").UsedRange.Offset(1).Resize(, 2).ClearContents
    Worksheets("tool").Range("A2").Resize(src.Rows.Count, src.Columns.Count).Value = src.Value2
    Worksheets("output").Range("B2").Value = Worksheets("tool").Range("E2").Value2
    Set grp = grp.Offset(1)
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: @tiffsmash problem is, if you want some VBA, you need to start the effort yourself. Try to start with some macro-recording, fine-tune the code as much as possible and post it in the question, we'll then help you finalize it.

Answer (score 0):

Do you really need a tool tab?
You can simply use the following formula in output tab:
`=Sumif(input!A:A,A3,input!B:C)`
and drag this formula down.